# HTML width of table headers

Tags: html

i wish to (unsurprisingly) line up the table headers with the columns. Ive tried using:

```
<th><div style='width:30px;'>ID</div>
```

but it doesnt appear to like it

Strangely enough, i was able to use a div to set an initial offset like:

```
<th><div style='margin-left:30px;' /></th>
```

so how can i give each table header an actual width?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code for the entire `<table>` please?

Comment: How do you mean line up? Tables automatically have the respective headers and cells in each column line up. Do you mean in a specific way? If so, which way?

Answer (score 1):

```
th{width:30px}
```

or give you `th` common classes. eg:

```
<tr>
<th class="header01"></th>
</tr>
```

then `.header01{width:30px}`

Probs gonna need to see your table if you want a better answer

Comment: After re reading your question it may be 'colspan' u need. Post your code please